# Upload Files To Server Using Retrofit 2

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2, multipartform-data

I am using Retrofit and for uploading image I have to pass parameter **files** **(type Array)**.
So, I have created a function as below :

```
private fun apiToUploadImage(path: String) {
    if (!CommonUtils.isNetworkConnected(mContext)) {
        return
    }

    //pass it like this
    var file = File(path)
    LogUtil.e(">>>>>>>>>>>",""+file.toString())
    var requestFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), file)

    // MultipartBody.Part is used to send also the actual file name
    var body: MultipartBody.Part =
        MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("files", file.name, requestFile)

    var bodyList = arrayListOf<MultipartBody.Part>()
    bodyList.add(body)

    ApiPresenter(this, apiService)
        .sampleFileHashMap(
            mContext, bodyList,
            Constant.ApiSuffix.WS_CODE_FILE_UPLOAD, true)
}
```

Here, Inside **ApiPresenter** I have done as below :

```
fun sampleFileHashMap(
    context: Context,
    params:List<MultipartBody.Part>,
    wsURL: String,
    isShowDialog: Boolean): Call<Any>? {
    if (isShowDialog) {
        showProgressDialog(context)
    }
    Timer("SettingUp", false).schedule(3000) {
        service?.sampleFileHashMap(wsURL, params)
            ?.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            ?.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            ?.subscribe(
                { response ->
                    LogUtil.e(
                        "##RESPONSE",
                        "======>>   " + (Gson().toJson(response).toString())
                    )
                    //                    LogUtil.e("##RESPONSE :: ", "======>>   $response")
                    retrofitListener.handleSuccessResponse(
                        Gson().toJson(response).toString(),
                        wsURL
                    )
                    dismissProgressDialog(context)
                },
                { error ->
                    LogUtil.e("##ERROR", "======>>" + error.message)
                    retrofitListener.handleErrorResponse(error.message!!)
                    dismissProgressDialog(context)
                }
            )
    }
    return null
}
```

My **ApiService** interface is below :

```
interface ApiService {
@Multipart
@POST
fun sampleFileHashMap(
    @Url url: String,
    @Part multipart: List<MultipartBody.Part>
): Observable<Any>
}
```

Called Api to upload image as below :

```
private fun apiToUploadImage(path: String) {
    if (!CommonUtils.isNetworkConnected(mContext)) {
        return
    }
    //pass it like this
    var file = File(path)
    LogUtil.e(">>>>>>>>>>>",""+file.toString())
    var requestFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), file)

    // MultipartBody.Part is used to send also the actual file name
    var body: MultipartBody.Part =
        MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("files", file.name, requestFile)
    var bodyList = arrayListOf<MultipartBody.Part>()
    bodyList.add(body)

    ApiPresenter(this, apiService)
        .sampleFileHashMap(
            mContext, bodyList,
            Constant.ApiSuffix.WS_CODE_FILE_UPLOAD, true)
}
```

But, getting this in log : **HTTP 400 Bad Request**

I understood that something am doing wrong in sending request. But, can't resolve it. What might be the issue?

**EDIT:**

below is the screenshot from postman : parameter name is **files**. Sending in Form data. 
[image: screenshot from postman]

Comment: server responded 400 but does it has an error message in the errorBody?
problems can be multipart data built incorrectly or field name that you provided is not correct

Comment: Why are you passing multipart as List<>? Try to remove List<> and try again. If it doesn't work, please test it with Postman client and post screenshots here.

Comment: Try sending array like this, `MultipartBody.Part[] filesMultipartArray = new MultipartBody.Part[10];` retrofit does gives problem while uploading array of images you can try volley if its still not working. Or check if there are cookies needed to be sent in headers in case. I had same issue so maintained cookies which worked.

Comment: Okay let me try. am posting postman screenshot soon.

Comment: @Shashanth edited question. please check. And I have tried removing List. Same issue..